# How to look for a value in another worksheet based on 2 criteria? VBA

Tags: vba, excel, function

I am trying to develop a function where the result will be a value (which is found in another worksheet) when meeting 2 criteria.

I have as follows:

```
Function PrecioUni(lic As String, part As Integer) As Double

Dim cell As Range

Set partidas = Worksheets("Análisis AP").Range("C13:C5000")

Select Case lic

    Case "Licitante 1"

        For Each cell In partidas
            If part = ActiveCell.Value Then
                PrecioUni = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value

            End If

        Next cell


End Select
End Function
```

There are 20 different lic= "Licitante 1, Licitante 2, ..." which is why I only put the first Case, and will write the rest when it works (as i would only have to change a few details).

The goal is to select 2 criteria (lic as String, part as Integer), after it has met criteria "Licitante 1",  look in the range partidas until it finds the same value as part, and finally return the value of the cell 10 columns to its right.

I believe the  issue lies in the If, but I am not sure, I would appreciate any help given, Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `ActiveCell` to `cell`

Comment: yep, that did it, didn´t even realize that, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Range.find to find some value in a range.

The problem in your code is that your using **Activecell** instead of your declared range "**cell**".

```
Function PrecioUni(lic As String, part As Integer) As Double

    Dim cell As Range

    Set partidas = Worksheets("Análisis AP").Range("C13:C5000")

    Select Case lic

    Case "Licitante 1"

        Set cell = partidas.Find(part, lookAt:=xwhole)

        If Not cell Is Nothing Then PrecioUni = cell.Offset(, 10).Value

    Case "Licitante 2"

        '[...]

    End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use your iterating variable and possibly convert the values.

`If part = CInt(Cell.Value) Then`

`PrecioUni = Cdbl(Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value)`